# Clash of clans not connecting to google play

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-play-services, clash-of-clans

I have just factory reset my device and tried to load my previous village back. But the game doesn't connect to Google Play. My game loads on my friend's device but not on mine. I am using Samsung Galaxy Star Pro. I have also cleared Google Play Services cache and data before performing a factory reset.

How can I get my Clash of Clans village back on my device?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following things:

- Update your Google Play, and delete Clash of Clans
- Update your device if possible, then reinstall your Clash of Clans
- Load your account using Google+, if you have it, or go to the help, choose "Contact us" and type your request. The Supercell community will tell you what you need to do and you would have your village back.

Comment: By 'Google Play' do you mean 'Google Play Games' or 'Google Play Services' or something else?